# Amazon payments integration

Tags: amazon-pay

I am struggling with integration of Amazon payments in JS, using a script for custom integration. As I saw in the documentation, there is a dynamic parameter 
`sellerOrderId`, which I added to the parameters generated from the express button integration. The problem begins when it's added to my generated express button parameters and sent - then I get redirected to a blank Amazon page:

- https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/gp/widgets/hosted/init

No error is sent in response.

Comment: Did you solve this?  I'm getting the blank page `https://payments.amazon.com/gp/widgets/hosted`.  There seems to be a `POST` but no `GET`.

Comment: Yes it was solved. It required changes on the backend side (PHP custom express button integration) and solution came from amazon payments tech support.